# Does Jon Snow create a precedent by doing this and why everyone is OK with it?

Tags: game-of-thrones

**Spoilers season 6, 7**

Wouldn’t John be creating a precedent by leaving the Watch after his

> resurrection? Technically it may be OK for him as the oath ends with the death.

Yet practically nobody in the realm knows about this though and he’s not eager to tell the story to others,

> (even Dany)

Why isn't he questioned by lords, etc. about the matter? Does he create precedent for future generations of watchers (assuming it's not the last WW invasion)? Isn't it reasonable for everyone to do the same thing?

Comment: You've tagged this to refer to the books as well as the TV series, but the incident in question hasn't yet occurred in the books, and may never.

Comment: "Night gathers, and now my watch begins. It shall not end until my death." And he died...

Comment: @BCdotWEB Anyone who didn't see him die and be ressurected would think him a liar. He is obviously not dead and people just don't come back from the dead either. If Jon Snow can make up a poor excuse to break his oath then anyone can.

Answer (score 5):

The Lord Commander of the Night's Watch can, and frequently does, send men south of the Wall, either on a short-term or long-term basis. For example: Yoren, Benjen Stark, Sam Tarly. Since Jon is the Lord Commander, he can assign himself to go wherever he wants, and so there's no reason for anyone else to think that he has broken his oath. Which, in fact, he hasn't; everything he's doing is aimed at defeating the White Walkers and thus defending the Wall.

Comment: But is he still The Lord Commander though? For me he has resigned by telling Edd “it’s your now”. Also can one combine the Lord Commander & King in The North titles?

Comment: @livingston I'm not sure that amounted to a formal resignation. If it did, then how could Jon have later sent the wildlings to man Eastwatch? And in any case, how could the northern and southern Lords have heard about it -- as far as they're concerned, Jon is still the Lord Commander.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Edd is the 999th Lord Commander now. And as Jon claims to be King of the North, Lords should definitely know is no longer Lord Commander. Probably the writers didn't think about that.

Comment: I also believe Jon never resigned, as there was no "election" for a new Lord Commander. Also, can't see any problem for one person to be both a King and  Lord Commander (of the Night Watch).

Comment: He goes around The North to every Lord to ask for help to overthrow the current Warden of the North and ruler of Winterfell,... Its obvious he is no longer serving as Lord Commander of the Watch,... He also wears armor with the Stark wolf on it instead of the black cloak of the Watch

Comment: "I shall take no wife, hold no lands, father no children. I shall wear no crowns and win no glory." Even if we pretend Jon is still a member of the NW and is just trying to defend the realm as a member of the NW should, the fact is he has been named King in the North (and accepted). He can't do that if he's in the NW. Jon says "My watch is ended." He knows he's no longer NW. Everybody knows.

Comment: @NyaNya I don't think he's broken any of that. Sansa holds the Stark lands; Jon doesn't. The North has no Crownlands held directly by the  King. He's been proclaimed King in the North, but I don't think we've seen him wear a crown. And obviously he has no wife and no children.

Comment: @MikeScott He calls himself the King of the North when meeting with Daenarys

Comment: @Vahx Yes, but he never vowed not to be a king. Was he wearing a crown?

Comment: @MikeScott Everybody knows full well what "I shall wear no crowns" means. It does not mean they will not play dress-up for Halloween. And this is feudalism. If Jon is King all the land in the North is his, only it's held for him by his vassal lords. Remember, he can give the Umber and Karstark lands to whomever he chooses. He chooses Ned and Alys, but he could do with them as he pleased.